# java code to append bytes to .dat file

Tags: java

Is there any way to append bytes to a file? Java code to get all bytes from PDF files in folder and append in .dat file but append is not working. If I use write it's working but it's only writing for first PDF file. What about other PDF files? Is there any way that I append all the bytes in a .dat file?

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class newxmlnew {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File folder = new File ("07072013");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    System.out.println("There are " + listOfFiles.length + " files"); 

    String filesin;



    int offset = 0;
    int size = 0;

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("07072013\\" + "jayraj" + ".dat",true);  

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

        File f = listOfFiles[i];

        System.out.println(i + " " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        if (f.isFile()) {

            filesin = listOfFiles[i].getName();

            if (filesin.endsWith("pdf")) {
                System.out.println(filesin);

                Path aPath = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath());

                System.out.println(filesin.toString());

                byte[] actualBytes = Files.readAllBytes(aPath);
                size = actualBytes.length;


               try { 
                out.write(actualBytes);
               } finally {
                   out.close();
               }
            }
        }
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Quick google helps this one.

Comment: I search in google, append bytes but.. it didn't give me any solution.. please help me.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare it outside your loop like so, note boolean at end is for append data.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("07072013\\" + "jayraj" + ".dat", true);
```

Then use

```
out.write(actualBytes)
```

A quick look at docs for [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29) shows this

As Erik mentioned also

Move the `finally` block and close call until after the for loop:

```
try {
   for ( all files ... ) {
       write ..
   }
} finally {
   out.close();
}
```

Comment: so i need to create file outside for loop.. I tried that, but it give me error stream closed!! I edit that code in my post please help me.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `FileOutputStream` inside your loop, which overwrites the previous file.

Comment: so, I need to crate out side for loop.. actually i tried that, but.. its give me error and it also didn't append..... please help me.. thanks!!

Comment: You also need to move your `out.close();` outside of your loop, otherwise the stream is closed after the first.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `finally` block. This is executed immediately after first write, wether it fails or not. So outputstream is always closed after writing one file.

```
           try { 
            out.write(actualBytes);
           } finally {
               out.close();
           }
```

Move the `finally` block and close call until after the for loop:

```
try {
   for ( all files ... ) {
       write ..
   }
} finally {
   out.close();
}
```